# How to use the Glide library with Azure Blob Container?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, android-glide

Is there any way to download images inside azure container using Glide library.
I have created virtual folder inside container is it possible to access tha whole folder.

Thank You

Help Appreciated !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to download images inside azure container using Glide library.

As I know, We can load image via Glide through `load(url)` method. In azure we can set **Public read access for blobs only** or **Full public read access** on Azure container to let it be accessible. Refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-manage-access-to-resources) for more information about how to manage read access to containers.  If you need to set azure container as **No public read access**, we can try to use [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1).

> I have created virtual folder inside container is it possible to access tha whole folder.

Azure blob does not support directory structure. all blobs are listed under a container. However Azure blob storage support slash ("/") in blob names. If you want to download whole folder files. you need to filter with folder name, then download each file.

Comment: how can i filter the folder inside container if i am using listblob method for multiple blob file....

Comment: is there any way i can get url of all blobs inside the container ? so that i can directly pass the url to glide ?

Comment: Azure support a lot of languages. If you using java, please search `ListBlobs(prefix: "prefixHere")` in your storage client library. If you want to get all urls under container, please use this method (`ListBlobs()`)  to get all blob names, then use this rule : `https://<account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container name>/<blob name>` to get all urls.